# Getting movie properties with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to do some calculations on movies I made in experiments. To do this I need some properties from the movies and it would be handy if I could automaticly detect them from the movie itself. In the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) I find the following code:

```
cv2.VideoCapture.get(propId) → retval
```

In the list below it states that for the total number of frames `propId` should be `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`. However when I try the following I get an error:

```
>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('runoff.MOV')
>> print cap.get('CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

If I input an integer in the code:

```
>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('runoff.MOV')
>> print cap.get(3)
1920.0
```

`CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` is the 4th item in the list in the documentation and indeed when I use the correct integer counter `3` I get this property. I wonder if there is a neater way to do this, making use of the class itself and writing a dictionary for it with all key, integer combinations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CV_CAP_PROP_*` constants can be accessed from the `cv2.cv` module:

```
cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

Unfortunately, not all useful things have been ported from `cv2` from  `cv` so it is generally a good idea to look in `cv2.cv` if you can't find what you are looking for in `cv2`.
Some constants, like `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_*` have been moved, for example.

**UPDATE**:-
For OpenCV 3.1 use:-

```
cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

Basically, the property name has been modified and the "CV_" in the beginning is no longer required.
(Credits to Blane in the answers section)

Answer (score 3):

I am using OpenCV 3.1 and the above methods suggested by Hannes do not work for me.  It seems that the method call and name formatting of properties have been slightly updated for OpenCV 3.1.  For example, `cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)` returns `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'` with OpenCV 3.1.  The following minor adjustment to the code worked for me:
`cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)`

Note that CV_ is no longer necessary as a prefix for the attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```